# Displaying Webforms on Content Types in Page Manager/Panels

Tags: 7, webforms, panels, chaos-tool-suite

The Webform module allows for a webform to be attached to each Content Type of the site.  I can "Enable webform functionality" on my Page and Blog Content types and don't need to use a separate "webform" content type, very cool!  This works great with Entity View Mode displays.

[image: Page Content Type - Webform Settings.]
However, when using the Node Template in Page Manager, I can't get the Webform to render after adding the "Node being viewed" Webform element.

[image: Page Manager Node Template]

My goal is to use Page Manager to display every node, with the possibility of a unique webform attached to that node.

I brought this up at a meetup recently and was advised that it may be a bug.  But I didn't think to ask where!  So, if you think I should bring this up in an issue queue, where do you think that would be, Webform, ctools, or Panels?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following way:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sumit,  Yes.  That is exactly what I have tried.

Comment: Oh!! Its working fine for me. Can't say what is the issue for you.